# How to change background color of a column in grid

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

1. I Have used that following code how that I use back color for my first grid column.
2. how do i use grid lines in windows phone 8.1 for grid.

```xml
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"  Name="mgrid" Margin="0,10,0,0" Background="White">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="190"   />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly? You use rows by setting the Grid.Row property.

Comment: i wanna just change background color of column 1 for all rows , is there any unified way..

Comment: You should probably edit your question to contain more details of what exactly is the problem and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your column definitions, you can create a rectangle which will sit inside your first Column Definition. Then, using the RowSpan property, make it appear as a full column.

For example:

```
<Rectangle Background="Red" Grid.RowSpan="6"/>
```

Comment: for every row i don't want to add a separate rectangle, is any unified way to archive for all rows of a specific column....

Comment: You don't need to, the RowSpan property will span this rectangle for 6 rows.

Comment: simple i want to make a grid which has many columns and rows with dynamic binding, i wanna make  first column color gray, and others column may be white, this grid has 'n' rows. now tell me clearly what should i do.

Comment: Insert that line of code inside your grid, after your column definitions. You should see that the rectangle is inside the first column, which spans all of the rows.

Comment: if i don't know that , how much number of column may generated by list so how can i forcefully add this tag Grid.RowSpan="6"

Comment: What you are asking is not possible in the traditional way. There are a couple of ways that you can achieve this:

1) Move the rectangle out of the grid and fix it's width to be the same as the first column width (Or even better, bind it). This method will allow the rectangle to appear behind the grid, giving it the illusion that it is part of the grid itself.

2) Using [this](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/), it may be possible to bind the RowSpan property to the attached property **RowCount** that the article creates.